# How to disconnect the openvpn client, when another client connects using same certificate?

Tags: networking, openvpn

I have openvpn server. There is no "duplicate-cn" in configuration file.

The sequence of my actions:

1. Client A connects to server. Everything works. Has access to server
   and to internet.
2. Client B connects to server, using same certificate as client A. Receive same ip as client A. Everything works. Has access to server and to internet.
3. Client A still connected. No access to server or to internet.

How to disconnect client A?

Server configuration:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log-append  openvpn.log
verb 3
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
```

Client configuration:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote example.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
pkcs12 client.p12
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `keepalive 10 120` in your server config which expands as follows:

```
ping 10
ping-restart 240
push "ping 10"
push "ping-restart 120"
```

You could replace the `keepalive` directive by something like this:

```
ping 10
ping-restart 240
push "ping 10"
push "ping-exit 60"
```

This causes the client to exit after 60 seconds pass without reception of a ping or other packet from remote.